# How to List all web Applications Under a Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint

Is There a way to get Lists of all web apps under a share point server. I am using client object model to develop application, with C#.  So, is it possible to do that with client object model and if possible then how can i do this. or any other way to do this from client side.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks for reply, But My Project Needs Client Side Programming, Is there any way to fetch Lists of all web apps on client side,

If Yes How can i do this.

If i am right i think our web browser also retrieve these lists in Under Central Administration Option, How web browser make it possible, can't we use this technique.

Comment: You can use the answer below in a web service and then have your client side code consume the service output. Central Administration probably uses code in the below answer and emits the HTML based on the results.

Answer (score 1):

I know using server object model.... It may help.............

```
   foreach (SPWebApplication webApplications in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
                           {
                               foreach (SPSite siteCollection in webApplications.Sites)
                               {
                                  foreach( SPWebCollection collWebsite in siteCollection.AllWebs){
                                   SPWebCollection collWebsite = site.AllWebs;
                                       foreach(SPWeb webSite in collWebsite)
                                          {
                                           // All web site
                                          }
                                    }
                                 }
                             }
```